# How servlet handle multiple request from same jsp page

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

Sorry friends if this question is very easy but i am confuse i unable to find out solution.

As we all know in spring MVC framework we create controller which will handle multiple request from same page using @requestmapping annotation.

but same thing i want to do in servlet how can i do ?

Suppose i have a jsp which which will contain a jqgrid,and two forms i want to use only one servlet to load the data into jqgrid and that servlet only will handle request from both the form . Since we have only doGet and doPost in servlet how one servlet fulfill all three request. Hope you understand my question if you have and link where i get sample or and tutorial link plz reply me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only easy way to do this would be to use a request parameter to control how the processing happens.

In a very basic example, you may have something like a `requestType` value that gets passed as either part of the query string or the request body.  You would assign values of 1-3 (or 0-2) with each value indicating a different type of request.  Your servlet would then parse the request accordingly.

This actually is how the `DispatcherServlet` in SpringMVC works.  There's only one servlet class instance and when a request comes in, it examines the query string along with other parts of the request to determine which controller should handle the request.

Comment: Which begs the question, why would the user want to re-implement this when DispatcherServlet is so stable and mature?

Comment: @Chris Thompson if you have any sample can you plz send me link